# compass direction on a grid

Tags: coordinates

I am working on a game that uses a grid system (think chess board).  Each tile on the board has a Location (row/column).  There is also the concept of a Direction (N, E, S, W, NE, SE, NW, SW).

Given two Locations I am calculating 3 direction things:

- The direction (N, E, S, W, NE, SW, NW, SW, NONE, or null.  Null is when the tiles do not line up exactly on one of the direction).
- The general direction (If it isn't one of the specific directions then it falls into the NE, SE, NW, SW general direction).
- The closest direction (if there is a tie it is null).

For example, (0, 0) -> (4, 3) has:

- direction of null
- general direction of SE
- closest direction of SE

and (0, 0) -> (4, 1) has:

- direction of null
- general direction of SE
- closest direction of S

The code works, but it is terribly ugly.  I am sure there must be a cleaner algorithm for setting the values, one with far less repetition.  Any thoughts on ways to reduce the duplicate code?

```
public final class Dimension
{
    private final int rowDistance;
    private final int columnDistance;
    private final Direction direction;
    private final Direction generalDirection;
    private final Direction closestDirection;

    public Dimension(final Location locationA,
                     final Location locationB)
    {
        if(locationA == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("locationA cannot be null");
        }

        if(locationB == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("locationB cannot be null");
        }

        rowDistance    = locationB.getRow()    - locationA.getRow();
        columnDistance = locationB.getColumn() - locationA.getColumn();

        // not moving at all
        if(rowDistance == 0 && columnDistance == 0)
        {
            direction        = Direction.NONE;
            generalDirection = Direction.NONE;
            closestDirection = Direction.NONE;
        }
        else
        {
            final int absoluteDifference;

            absoluteDifference = Math.abs(Math.abs(rowDistance) - Math.abs(columnDistance));

            // North Westish
            if(rowDistance <= 0 && columnDistance <= 0)
            {
                final int north;
                final int west;
                final int northWest;

                if(absoluteDifference == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.NORTH_WEST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.NORTH_WEST;
                }
                else if(rowDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.WEST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.WEST;
                }
                else if(columnDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.NORTH;
                    generalDirection = Direction.NORTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction        = null;
                    generalDirection = Direction.NORTH_WEST;
                }

                north     = Math.abs(columnDistance);
                west      = Math.abs(rowDistance);
                northWest = Math.abs(
                               Math.abs(Math.max(rowDistance, columnDistance)) - 
                               Math.abs(Math.min(rowDistance, columnDistance)));

                if(northWest < west && northWest < north)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.NORTH_WEST;
                }
                else if(west < northWest && west < north)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.WEST;
                }
                else if(north < northWest && north < west)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.NORTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    closestDirection = null;
                }
            }
            // North Eastish
            else if(rowDistance <= 0 && columnDistance >= 0)
            {
                final int north;
                final int east;
                final int northEast;

                if(absoluteDifference == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.NORTH_EAST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.NORTH_EAST;
                }
                else if(rowDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.EAST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.EAST;
                }
                else if(columnDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.NORTH;
                    generalDirection = Direction.NORTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction        = null;
                    generalDirection = Direction.NORTH_EAST;
                }

                north     = Math.abs(columnDistance);
                east      = Math.abs(rowDistance);
                northEast = Math.abs(
                               Math.abs(Math.max(rowDistance, columnDistance)) -             
                               Math.abs(Math.min(rowDistance, columnDistance)));

                if(northEast < east && northEast < north)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.NORTH_EAST;
                }
                else if(east < northEast && east < north)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.EAST;
                }
                else if(north < northEast && north < east)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.NORTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    closestDirection = null;
                }
            }
            // South Westish
            else if(rowDistance >= 0 && columnDistance <= 0)
            {
                final int south;
                final int west;
                final int southWest;

                if(absoluteDifference == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.SOUTH_WEST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.SOUTH_WEST;
                }
                else if(rowDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.WEST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.WEST;
                }
                else if(columnDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.SOUTH;
                    generalDirection = Direction.SOUTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction        = null;
                    generalDirection = Direction.SOUTH_WEST;
                }

                south     = Math.abs(columnDistance);
                west      = Math.abs(rowDistance);
                southWest = Math.abs(
                               Math.abs(Math.max(rowDistance, columnDistance)) - 
                               Math.abs(Math.min(rowDistance, columnDistance)));

                if(southWest < west && southWest < south)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.SOUTH_WEST;
                }
                else if(west < southWest && west < south)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.WEST;
                }
                else if(south < southWest && south < west)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.SOUTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    closestDirection = null;
                }
            }
            // South Eastish
            else
            {
                final int south;
                final int east;
                final int southEast;

                if(absoluteDifference == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.SOUTH_EAST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.SOUTH_EAST;
                }
                else if(rowDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.EAST;
                    generalDirection = Direction.EAST;
                }
                else if(columnDistance == 0)
                {
                    direction        = Direction.SOUTH;
                    generalDirection = Direction.SOUTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = null;
                    generalDirection = Direction.SOUTH_EAST;                    
                }

                south     = Math.abs(columnDistance);
                east      = Math.abs(rowDistance);
                southEast = Math.abs(
                              Math.abs(Math.max(rowDistance, columnDistance)) - 
                              Math.abs(Math.min(rowDistance, columnDistance)));

                if(southEast < east && southEast < south)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.SOUTH_EAST;
                }
                else if(east < southEast && east < south)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.EAST;
                }
                else if(south < southEast && south < east)
                {
                    closestDirection = Direction.SOUTH;
                }
                else
                {
                    closestDirection = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRowDistance()
    {
        return (rowDistance);
    }

    public int getColumnDistance()
    {
        return (columnDistance);
    }

    public Direction getDirection()
    {
        return (direction);
    }

    public Direction getGeneralDirection()
    {        
        return (generalDirection);
    }

    public Direction getClosestDirection()
    {        
        return (closestDirection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compute the distance much as you have, then I would pass the orthogonal distances to Math.Atan2 to compute a heading H that can be scaled (int)Math.Round(H * 4 / Math.PI) into the range 0-7 as a hash that counts clockwise through the compass points from N, and which you can directly cast into your enum assuming you enumerate clockwise.

Comment: In the end I didn't use this, but it got me to where I needed to be :-)  Thanks!